# Call to undefined method UserModel::addUser()

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

Other functions from the same model are working fine, I'm only having problem with two of them, which both interact with the database. Works locally.

From the error log. **PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method UserModel::getScreens()**

I've searched all through google and can't see the reason behind why these to functions wont run on the server. Login also talks to the database and works okay.

I've tried different naming conventions for the calls `$this->UserModel->method()` `$this->userModel->method()` etc. Same with changing the loading model. `$this->load->model('UserModel', ' ', TRUE);`

**user.php** (controller)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

session_start();

class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('usermodel','',TRUE);
    }

    public function register(){
       ..........
       $addUser = $this->usermodel->addUser($this->input->post());
       ..........
    }

    public function screens($id = FALSE){
        $data = $this->checkStatus('screens');
        //userInfo is coming from the checkStatus function.
        //Have verified with a var_dump($user_id) and it appears
        $user_id = $data['userInfo'][0]['id'];
        $data['screens'] = $this->Usermodel->getScreens($user_id);
        if($data){
            $data['title'] = 'My SCREENs';
            if($id){
                $data['id'] = $id;
                $this->load->template('screenview', $data);
            } else {
                $this->load->template('screens', $data);
            }
        }
    }

    public function login(){
        //This works
        ..........
        $result = $this->usermodel->login($email, $password);
        ..........
    }
}
```

**usermodel.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class UserModel extends CI_Model{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->salt = "_________";

    }

    function getScreens($userID){
    //This doesn't work
        $this -> db -> select('*');
        $this -> db -> from('screens');
        $this -> db -> where('user_id = ' . "'" . $userID . "'");
        $query = $this -> db -> get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }

    function addUser($data){
    //This doesn't work
         $data = array(
           'first_name' => $data['firstname'] ,
           'last_name' => $data['lastname'] ,
           'email' => $data['email'],
           'dob' => $data['dob-day'] . '/' . $data['dob-month'] . '/' . $data['dob-year'],
           'height' => $data['height'],
           'weight' => $data['weight'],
           'password' => sha1($data['password1'] . $this->salt),
           'gender' => $data['gender']
        );
        $added = $this->db->insert('users', $data);
        if($added){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function login($email, $password){
    //This works
        $this -> db -> select('id, email, password');
        $this -> db -> from('users');
        $this -> db -> where('email = ' . "'" . $email . "'");
        $this -> db -> where('password = ' . "'" . sha1($password . $this->salt) . "'");
        $this -> db -> limit(1);

        $query = $this -> db -> get();

        if($query -> num_rows() == 1){
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code of the methods failing in the model. Otherwise we will just be guessing

Comment: Updated the model with further lines of code

Comment: I would suggest you to consider naming all functions with for instance `add_user` instead of camelCasing. All of Codeigniters functions do this approach, and often makes it easier to maintain your code.

Comment: Thanks, just made the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with git.

Every time I was making a change, git was recognising the file as `userModel.php`, instead of `usermodel.php` so every time the call was being made it would look inside `usermodel.php` and nothing was there except the login function.

=/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use multiple capital letters in your usermodel model.  First letter MUST be capitalized and all others MUST be lowercase.

Try:

```
Class Usermodel extends CI_Model{
```

And in your controllers

```
$this->load->model('Usermodel', '', TRUE);
$this->Usermodel->getScreens()
```

will post documentation in a second

EDIT:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

View rules under "Anatomy of Model".  I spent way too much time a while back trying to solve this exact problem when I first started with CI :)

EDIT 2:

Also, I had this problem a long time ago too, but $this->usermodel->whatever() would work on my local machine but NOT on the server.  Reason?  Apache is a pain when it comes to capital letters.  Make SURE you have all your U's capitalized in $this->Usermodel

Comment: wow, really?  Is it the same error?  Also, what is $this->salt referring to in your Usermodel constructor?

Comment: OH, the method isn't passing in any parameters!!  Unless you're hiding some code, the $user_id variable in $this->Usermodel->getScreens is not declared elsewhere.  You have a parameter in public function screens($id = null) but you use getScreens($user_id), not getScreens($id).
`$this->Usermodel->getScreens($id)` instead of `$this->Usermodel->getScreens($user_id)`

Comment: There's like another 5+ functions in the controller. $user_id is being set by something else inside the controller. Everything is passing fine, including var_dumps right beside the line making a call to the model. I've put a die() on the first like of getScreens in the model and it's not being reached.

Comment: is addUser not working?  You say there are 2 functions that are not working.  Reason is that I KNOW I'm right regarding my post about changing the model to Usermodel and using `$this->Usermodel->addUser()`.  I had a problem with it working fine on my local machine but when it went up to the server the capitalizations screwed everything up.  See my second edit.

Comment: Yeah I get the same error message when hitting against addUser. **PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method UserModel::addUser()**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16898/discussion-between-i-could-be-wrong-and-bankzilla)